# Save an email attachment to a designated bucket

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

App Engine allows one to listen to incoming emails. I'd like to then read attachments and write them to a GCS bucket. `google.cloud.storage` is not available in the standard environment, and `cloudstorage`, which is available, doesn't allow writing in any other bucket but the default one.

I tried also in flexible env, but InboundMailHandler is not available in that case: "The App Engine Mail service is not available outside the standard environment" https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating

Is there any way to write these files to a designated bucket, in a standard environment?

```
import logging
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
        plaintext_bodies = mail_message.bodies('text/plain')
        html_bodies = mail_message.bodies('text/html')

        if hasattr(mail_message, 'attachments'):
            for filename, filecontent in mail_message.attachments:
                # write filecontent to a bucket


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the bucket while writing in `cloud storage`.

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
```

You can fetch the particular bucket by the above code. Then you can use this bucket to write in your `cloud storage`.
Keep in mind while writing file specify your filename as below:

```
file_name = '/' + 'BUCKET_NAME' + '/' + 'FILE_NAME'
```

For more detailed code regarding reading and writing, you can refer 
[***Cloud Read/Write Documentation.***](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage)

Detailed Read/Write Code: [***Github Google Cloud***](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/storage/appengine-client/main.py)

*Hope this answers your question!!*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, for a flask app, this is how you would do it:

In `requirements.txt` add `google-cloud-storage`

```
Flask==2.1.2
appengine-python-standard>=1.0.0
google-cloud-storage
```

In your `main.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import wrap_wsgi_app
from google.cloud import storage
from datetime import date

app = Flask(__name__)

# Enable access to bundled services
app.wsgi_app = wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app)


@app.route("/_ah/mail/<path>", methods=["POST"])
def receive_mail(path):
    message = mail.InboundEmailMessage(request.get_data())

    print(f"Received greeting for {message.to} at {message.date} from {message.sender}")
    for content_type, payload in message.bodies("text/plain"):
        print(f"Text/plain body: {payload.decode()}")

        for filename, filecontent in message.attachments:
            print("Received attachment: ", filename)
            storage_client = storage.Client()
            bucket = storage_client.bucket("BUCKET NAME")
            blob = bucket.blob(f'{date.today():%Y-%d-%m}/{filename}')

            with blob.open("wb") as f:
                f.write(filecontent.decode())

    return "OK", 200
```

This is what my `app.yaml` looks like:

```
runtime: python39
app_engine_apis: true
service: email-service
inbound_services:
- mail
- mail_bounce
```